# Как использовать select с массивами в c# (mysql)?

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня имеется база данных и мне надо отсортировать данные в ней. Я создал массив строк и хочу сравнить их с нужным столбцом в каждой строке и вывести нужные строчки. Но таблица обновляется после вывода каждой строки.
то есть, если у меня есть массив строк: `string array = {"123,"321,"456"}` то моя таблица покажет только одну строку, в которой содержится один из членов массива. Но мне нужно чтобы выводило все строчки которые содержат один из этих элементов. 
Как это сделать? Может есть какой то способ передачии массива строк в метод `Contains`? Или как не обновлять постоянно таблицу?

```
bool[] check = new bool[]{spain_check.Checked, france_check.Checked, england_check.Checked, germany_check.Checked, brazil_check.Checked,
                                        argentina_check.Checked, belgium_check.Checked, italy_check.Checked, netherland_check.Checked, portugal_check.Checked};
            string[] str = new string[]{spain_check.Text, france_check.Text, england_check.Text, germany_check.Text, brazil_check.Text,
                                        argentina_check.Text, belgium_check.Text, italy_check.Text, netherland_check.Text, portugal_check.Text};
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if (check[i] == false)
                {
                    str[i] = "";
                }
            }
            string msg = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if (str[i] == "")
                    continue;
                msg += str[i] + '\n';
                var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                            where o.country.Contains(str[i])
                            select o;
                mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Это СО на русском,тут забанить могут вопрос на английском)

Comment: Перепутал, удалю сейчас)

Comment: Не надо удалять. Переведите.

Comment: @TEA, не пугайте людей, за такое не банят точно, только закроют вопрос, но его можно переоткрыть, если автор исправит

Comment: Еще бы title скорректировать бы.

Comment: @АндрейNOP так я про вопрос говорил,мб не так выразился:)